# Multi-stability potential is suitable for interdisciplinary branches of science?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biophysics, models, complex-systems

The potential function $V(x) = c(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$ with constants $a,b,c$ and some variable $x$ has two minima: One at $x=a$ and another at $x=b$.

When plugging this potential function in Newton's equation of Motion, one obtains e.g. oscillations around one of the two minima. If there is enough kinetic energy, Transition from one minima to another is possible. Thus, this potential function might be suitable to make a model of some non-physics phenomena.

I have seen that such potential function is good for modeling chemical reactions.

Can such a potential function be used to describe even a lot more complicated phenomena, e.g. to describe the Dynamics of Neurons (where one minimum may be a neuron which has no activity, and the other minimum is where the neuron "fires")? Or even other phenomena?

Comment: Potentials with multiple minima are used to model a lot of nonlinear dynamics phenomena.

Comment: Can These be used even to describe complicated things like biological or sociological structures?

Comment: What usually happens is that a certain pattern of behavior is observed experimentally and then mathematical models are explored that exhibit similar patterns

Comment: It is similar to reasoning by analogy

Comment: Since leaving the above comments I found this paper: "On Soliton Propagation in Biomembranes and Nerves," Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences USA, Vol 102, No. 28, 9790-9795, July 12, 2005.  Solitons are solutions to nonlinear wave equations where the field function has multiple minima, hence this paper is an example of ab application to neurodynamics.  A less technical description of the subject is given in an article by Douglas Fox in the April, 2018 issue of Scientific american (page 61).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be very useful.

Mechanical systems are often good toy models for more complicated systems. The one you describe is the [Duffing oscillator](http://scholarpedia.org/article/Duffing_oscillator), and it has long been used (check [scholar](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=duffing+potential+neurons&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhxKnAhbfaAhWMCuwKHQU_A5EQgQMIJzAA)) to model neurons. Quoting from this 1995 [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0013-4694(95)00088-G) by R. Srebro:

> Thirty years ago Zeeman conjectured that the dynamics of the EEG might be modeled by the “equation of motion” of a Duffing oscillator [...] Predictions based on Duffing oscillator dynamics are substantially better than those based on the assumption that each neuronal group follows a simpler exponentially damped sinusoid or a function that simulates a post-synaptic potential.

There are of course several more realistic models. In particular, the [Hodgkin–Huxley model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model) earned its authors the 1963 Nobel Prize in physiology. Also, simulating aspects of brain dynamics is an important topic in the field of Complex Networks, where, for whatever dynamics you choose for the individual neurons (or brain regions), the focus is on the collective behavior, network topology, etc.